# C pointer---function relation

Tags: c

We called the function `foo(&x, &y)` in the `main` function but then why did we call `swap (x, y)` inside `void foo` function as `swap (&x, &y)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void foo(int*p1, int*p2) {
    *p1 += *p2;
    swap(p1, p2);
    *p2 *= *p1;
}

int main(){
    int x = 5, y = 9;
    foo(&x, &y);

    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    printf("y=%d\n", y);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error or mtsake you have in your code

Comment: no code error just why we used & operator in swap function but we just swap (x, y)

Comment: main function swap(&x,&y)////// void foo swap(x,y) what is different

Comment: I'm not convinced the proposed duplicates answer this question. This one is about why it's not the same syntax throughout. I could not find another one close enough to asking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the type of the parameters you call the function with.

**First case:**

The type of `x` is `int` and the `foo` function is expecting `int *`.

So you have `foo(&x, &y);`

**Second case:**

The type of `p1` is `int *` and the `swap` function is also expecting `int *`.

So you have `swap(p1, p2);`

Comment: thanks senerh I understand